# pycurl library issue while using yum command in RHEL 7.1

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, yum, pycurl, rhel7

I updated the python in RHEL 7.1 machine from 2.7 to 3.6 and updated the pycurl library from a third party website, which caused the below issue.
Kindy help me in resolving it.

```
[root@testVM build]# yum

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was: `pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (openssl) is different from compile-time ssl backend (none/other).
Please install a package which provides this module, or verify that the module is installed correctly.
It's possible that the above module doesn't match the current version of Python, which is: 2.7.5 (default, Feb 20 2018, 09:19:12) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]
If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to the yum faq at: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

[root@testVM build]# which python /usr/bin/python
[root@testVM build]# python --version 
Python 3.6.4
[root@testVM build]#
```